# Migrate am2cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, automake

I try to transfer into some CMake program and there is a function generating header files from the xml.

Makefile.am

```
adaptor_glue.hpp: dbus_introspect.xml
    $(DBUSXX_XML2CPP) '$<' --adaptor='$@'

proxy_glue.hpp: dbus_introspect.xml
    $(DBUSXX_XML2CPP) '$<' --proxy='$@'
```

configure

```
DBUSXX_XML2CPP='$(top_builddir)/dbus-c++/tools/dbusxx-xml2cpp'
```

How I can do it on cmake?

Comment: Cloused! I use "execute_process"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is:

```
add_custom_command(OUTPUT proxy_glue.hpp adaptor_glue.hpp PRE_BUILD
                   COMMAND "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/dbus-c++/tools/dbusxx-xml2cpp" ARGS "./dbus_introspect.xml" "--proxy=./proxy_glue.hpp" "--adaptor=./adaptor_glue.hpp"
                   )
```